# Smart UV Unwrap on Joined Object Breaks Textures

Tags: uv

I have a simple build into a Joined object. When I try to smart uv unwrap the object, the textures break.

Here's what I did:

- OBJ> A to select all of the individual objects
- OBJ> Shift-D, Enter, Cntl-J
- EDIT> A to select all
- OBJECT DATA PANEL> + new uv map named JoinedSmartUnwrapMap
- UV EDITOR PANE> + create new image, 1024x1024, no alpha
- EDIT> U , smart uv unwrap

But, when I smart unwrap, the textures blow up.
**Am I missing a vector input node of some sort on the individual wood material and the poster material? for the objects prior to joining?**

Joined object before smart uv unwrap:

[image: Before smart uv unwrap:]

Joined object after smart uv unwrap
[image: After smart uv unwrap]

[Files saved in the state just before the Smart UV Unwrap](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZlV4aZSWgqoLp5sr9DgU24mzq8eNoQOe)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Files on other services tend to "vanish", thus rendering your question and possible answers practically useless in the future. Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135905/edit) link at the bottom of your question and add the link given by blend-exchange to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here what's should help. As I understand you want to bake textures.

1. Join objects into one.
2. Duplicate object and move to different layer. Name it "bake".
3. Remove all materials from "bake" object. Create new material for it. 
   (image tex > Diffuse > output).
4. Create new map for baking (in UV editor) and save it as "Bake_diff"
5. UV unwrap "bake" obj with smart UV unwrap.
6. Select "Bake_diff" in image texture node as active one.
7. Set background on full white.
8. Go to Bake setup. Tick 'Selected to Active' and setup 'Ray Distance' to 0.100
9. Now select both layers, select first obj with textures and as second, the bake one. (make sure image texture nod with "Bake_diff" is selected)
10. Bake and wait.
11. Save map F3

There's a blend. Prepared, just do 9 & 10.

[image]